# Azure SQL Database and SSIS packages development

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

I must decide whether to get SQL Server Standard license or subscribe to Azure SQL Database for the needs of a small company. Basically what I need is the possibility to develop SSIS packages for data import from Excel and schedule their execution + develop job(s) for sending automated e-mails to customers. As I have zero administration skills I think Azure services would be a better option, but on the other side I cannot find good information on how to develop SSIS directly under the Azure environment. Would I still need SQL Server for that?

Comment: what's your question, schedule the import data from excel to Azure SQL database with SSIS job?

Comment: This + develop the actual SSIS job in Azure without SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

For import data from excel to Azure SQL database with SSIS, you can reference this tutorials: [Import data from Excel or export data to Excel with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15)

This article describes the connection information that you have to provide, and the settings that you have to configure, to import data from Excel or export data to Excel with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS).

You also need download [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15) to help you create the SSIS package. Reference tutorial: [Create Packages in SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/create-packages-in-sql-server-data-tools?view=sql-server-ver15).

All of these need the SQL server environment support. We can not develop the actual SSIS job in Azure without SQL Server.

Comment: That means I can develop SSIS using Visual Studio and SSDT but still need SQL Server? This is not optimal for me because I'd need SQL Server license too which makes it even more expensive.

Comment: At least, when you connect to Azure SQL database with other tools, you need the SQL server driver.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need SSIS to import data from Excel files to Azure SQL Database. You just need to schedule upload those Excel documents to Azure Storage Acoount and from there you can use OPENQUERY or BULK INSERT to import them to Azure SQL Database.

First create a SCOPED CREDENTIAL with the secret key of the Storage Account.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL UploadInvoices
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=2018-03-28&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwdlac&se=2019-08-31T02:25:19Z&st=2019-07-30T18:25:19Z&spr=https&sig=KS51p%2BVnfUtLjMZtUTW1siyuyd2nlx294tL0mnmFsOk%3D';
```

Now create an external data source that maps the Storage Account.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureInvoices
    WITH (
        TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
        LOCATION = 'https://newinvoices.blob.core.windows.net',
        CREDENTIAL = UploadInvoices
    );
```

Import Excel documents using OPENROWSET.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'week3/inv-2017-01-19.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
   FORMAT = 'CSV',
   FORMATFILE='invoices.fmt',
   FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices'
   ) AS DataFile;
```

Using BULK INSERT, specify the container on the Storage Account and file description:

```
BULK INSERT Colors2
FROM 'week3/inv-2017-01-19.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
      FORMAT = 'CSV');
```

You can automate this using Azure Automation to schedule execution of a stored procedure using OPENQUERY and BULK INSERT to import Excel files.